# GCC optimization of __builtin functions used in a macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros

If I have a macro like:

```
#define MAX_SIZE ((1<<18)-1)
```

I can rest assured that by runtime this math has been done already and MAX_SIZE is a literal.

My question is, what if I use a __builtin function such as:

```
#define BIT_OFFSET (__builtin_clz(MAX_SIZE))
```

does this turn into a constant by run time as well?

Comment: Macros are pure text replacement.  If `__builtin_clz()` is not a macro, it executes at runtime.  Most compilers have a flag that will output your file post-preprocessing if you want to see exactly what happens.

Comment: Isn't the `__builtin_*` family of functions gcc intrinsics, implying that they get inlined unless explicitly disabled?

Comment: GCC intrinsics are GCC intrinsics, not macros. Sometimes they're implemented with function calls, sometimes they're inlined, sometimes they're evaluated at compile time. I don't know whether this specific one can be evaluated at compile time though.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think all of GCC's `__builtin_*` functions special-case constant arguments and generate a constant result that's usable in the full strength of C's sense of "constant expression" (i.e. you can even use them as bitfield widths, sizes of arrays in structs, etc.).

Comment: @R.. There's nothing in the documentation that says that, and we can be sure that __builtin_abort, among others, does not generate a constant result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some values, some machines, and some versions of some compilers, __builtin_clz(constant) will be evaluated at compile time. But there is no guarantee that it will be evaluated at compile time for all values, all machines, and all compilers. Use gcc -S to see what your compiler does on your target machine.

Comment: Alright, after compiling a test program and disassembling it turns out that yes it is optimized into a literal value in this case.

Comment: @vaebnkehn And you didn't accept this answer because ...?

Comment: There you go! Have some internet points 

Comment: @vaebnkehn Welcome back to SO after 9 years. :-)